# How do I write words inside a square root without the words getting italicized?

Tags: italic, sqrt

I wrote `$\sqrt{n^{\frac{number of factors of n}{2}}}$` but the "number of factors of n" is getting italicized. Can someone help with this please?
Thank you

Comment: With use of the `amsmath` package, you can just type `$\sqrt{n^{\frac{\text{number of factors of } n}{2}}}$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 9):

I'd avoid text like that in formulas. Anyway, here are three realizations, in the order “ugly-bad-good”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A not very nice formula that's rather difficult to read
\[
\sqrt{n^{\frac{\textup{number of factors of $n$}}{2}}}
\]
Let's try to improve it by using a slashed fraction
\[
\sqrt{n^{(\textup{number of factors of $n$})/2}}
\]
but really you should define $d(n), ν(n), τ(n) or σ_0(n)$ to be the number of factors of $n$
and type your formula as
\[
\sqrt{n^{σ_0(n)/2}}=\sqrt[4]{n^{σ_0(n)}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between \textup and \text ?

Comment: Not to mention that "where n is..." avoids putting a period  inside a displayed equation.

Answer (score 6):

[image: roman in math]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\sqrt{n^{\frac{\text{number of factors of } n}{2}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is more semantic to use `$\sqrt{ n^{ \frac{ \text{number of factors of $n$} }{2} } }$`.

Comment: You're right. Either way, I'd never do that kind of thing in a document, it was just to give a possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

And without any package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    $\sqrt{n^{\frac{\mbox{\tiny number of factors of } n}{2}}}$
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    $\sqrt{n^{\frac{\mathrm{number~of~factors~of~}n}{2}}}$
\end{document}
```